# Hotel Reservation system in Django: How to make a room unavailable to other users for a period of time

Tags: python, django

I am building a hotel reservation system for my a-level coursework and my problem is when a user books a room I want to make sure no other user can reserve that room for the duration of the time period that the room is occupied.

I tried using iteration to loop over the dates and have a boolean value that is set to true when the room is reserved and false when it is not.

Here is my models

```
class Room(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to='Pictures')
   desc = models.TextField()
   price = models.IntegerField()
   is_reserved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   number_of_people = models.PositiveIntegerField()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Room'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Rooms'

 class Reservation(models.Model):

    check_in = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    check_out = models.DateField()
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Reservation'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Reservations'
```

This is my function in views where it will loop over the checkin and check out dates inputted by the user and make sure that no other user can reserve that room for those dates

```
def confirm(request, pk = None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pk:
             room_id = Room.objects.get(pk = pk)
             guest_id = request.user
             check_in = request.session['check_in'] 
             check_out = request.session['check_out']
             reservation = Reservation(
             check_in = check_in, 
             check_out = check_out,
             room_id = room_id.id,
             guest_id = guest_id.id
             )
             reservation.save()

             book_in = datetime.strptime(check_in, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
             book_out = datetime.strptime(check_out, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
             reserved = False

             delta = timedelta(days = 1)
             while book_in <= book_out:
                  room_id.reserved = True
                  book_in += delta
             else:
                  room_id.reserved = False

      return render(request, "system/reserve.html", args)
```

The html page where I want to display that the room is reserved if the check in and check out dates match those in the reservation table for the same room

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'system:confirm' room.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>{{room.name}}</h1>
    <img src="{{room.img.url}}">
    <h3 >£{{room.price}}</h3>
    <h5 >{{room.desc}}</h5>
    {% if room_id.reserve == True %}
    <h4>This room has been reserved</h4>
    {% else %}
    <button name="confirm_reservation" type="submit"> Reserve Room 
    </button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
</body>
```

I expect a message that a room is reserved (shown in my html block) if either the check in or check out dates is in the reservation table and in between the check in and check out dates. For example: if a room is reserved from the 20th august 2019 to the 25th august 2019 then my check in or check out dates must not fall in between and including the 20th august 2019 and the 25th august 2019 if I want to reserve the room i should get message being displayed to me that i can't. Instead I am able to reserve the room anytime I chose since my boolean value is always false. I want to make the value true for only that period of time and if the check in and check out is not in and in between the check in and check out dates in the reservation table say 8th september 2020 to 10th september 2020 then my boolean value should be false and I am able to reserve that room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you want to do is ensure that there are no existing reservations for this room, that overlap with the requested check_in and check_out dates. We can break this down into three cases:

1. There is no existing reservation which has a check_in date starting before the requested check_in date, and a check_out date ending anytime after the requested check_in date. Also, adding indexes to both these fields will help us speed the queries, when your site gets busy
2. There is no existing reservation which has a check_in date starting before the requested check_out date, and a check_out date ending anytime after the requested check_out date
3. There is a reservation which lies between the two requested check-in/check-out dates

The image bellow illustrates these cases. Blue represents a requested reservation, while orange represents an existing reservation which invalidates the request -- Note there is an error in the third case, the colours should be swapped:

[image: J13qq.png]
<sub>(source: [imge.to](https://a.imge.to/2019/08/18/J13qq.png))</sub>

We cover these two cases with two cases, and then check that there are no matching queries using `exists()` method. If any matching reservation exists, we return to the same page, displaying an error. Otherwise, we proceed to confirm the requested reservation and then redirect to another page to display the success message:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def confirm(request, pk = None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pk:
            invalid_dates = False
            #get the room 
            room = Room.objects.get(pk = pk)
            guest_id = request.user
            check_in = request.session['check_in'] 
            check_out = request.session['check_out']

            # check wether the dates are valid
            # case 1: a room is booked before the check_in date, and checks out after the requested check_in date
            case_1 = Reservation.objects.filter(room=room, check_in__lte=check_in, check_out__gte=check_in).exists()

            # case 2: a room is booked before the requested check_out date and check_out date is after requested check_out date
            case_2 = Reservation.objects.filter(room=room, check_in__lte=check_out, check_out__gte=check_out).exists()
            
            case_3 = Reservation.objects.filter(room=room, check_in__gte=check_in, check_out__lte=check_out).exists()


            # if either of these is true, abort and render the error
            if case_1 or case_2 or case_3:
                  return render(request, "system/reserve.html", {"errors": "This room is not available on your selected dates"})                  
             
             # dates are valid             
             reservation = Reservation(
             check_in = check_in, 
             check_out = check_out,
             room_id = room.id,
             guest_id = guest_id.id
             )

             reservation.save()

             #redirect to success page (need to define this as a separate view)
             return redirect("/reservation_success")


      return render(request, "system/reserve.html", args)
```

`html`

```
body>

    <p>{{errors}}</p>
    
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'system:confirm' room.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>{{room.name}}</h1>
    <img src="{{room.img.url}}">
    <h3 >£{{room.price}}</h3>
    <h5 >{{room.desc}}</h5>
    {% if room_id.reserve == True %}
    <h4>This room has been reserved</h4>
    {% else %}
    <button name="confirm_reservation" type="submit"> Reserve Room 
    </button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
</body>
```

### Notes

- This solution is not optimal. We are performing 2 queries which can be merged into one, but this would require the use of a logical OR, and use of Django's `Q`
- For better design, it would be better to use a `form` for your validation, and add validation within it. But for the sake of your project, this would work.
- You do not need the boolean field in your Room model, since we are handling the checks based on the check_in and check_out dates.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out and your theory is correct. But even after I typed out your code and changed a few things such as redirecting to my home page instead. I first get an unbound local error saying checkin is not defined, so i changed it to check_in and placed the check_in = request.session['check_in'] above the lines where case_1 = along with the check_out (not sure if that was the correct thing to do). Then I get another error when the values of the check_in and check_out match the cases 1, 2 or 3 as you mentioned. it is saying NoReverseMatch found with args '("",)'.

Comment: Yes you are right, some lines had to move up in the method (I have edited my code). Do you know which line this error is coming from? I suspect its from the `redirect` method. You need to create that url in your urls.py file

Comment: I believe the error was from my urls.py so that fault was on my behalf but I was unable to display the error message to the user on the reserve.html if the room was reserved so I would just send them to another page to display the error, which is perfectly fine. Also may I ask for one more addition if it's not too much to ask, I would need another case which would be the the same as case 3 but with the colours switched around so a requested reservation being larger than an existing reservation but sharing similar dates.